# Why controllers in ASP.NET Core 6 with React template are not found when deployed to IIS?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, .net-6.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and picked ASP.NET Core 6 with React template as my template. Controllers in development mode work fine no problem. But when I tried to publish it to IIS, it cannot reach the controller. Saying, http 404 not found error.

Even if you picked the template and publish it directly, it still have the same error. Controllers or endpoint cannot be reached.

What config or settings am I missing?

Comment: I would like to confirm with you whether you have installed Asp.Net Core hosting bundle before hosting the Asp.Net core site on the IIS? If not, you could install it from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.5-windows-hosting-bundle-installer). After that, try to host your site to the IIS and see whether it works.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for the response. I tried installing the hosting bundle you gave me but still. It can't reach the controllers. Any suggestions?

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you provide the detailed steps you took to create a sample project. Also, inform us which steps you took to host the site on the IIS? Which OS and which version of the IIS you are using? It could help us understand the issue in a better way.